# Proof of the inequality $\sup_{x\in [a, b]} (f(x)) ^2 \le (b-a) \int_a ^b(f'(x)) ^2 dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, solution-verification

Given that $f\in C^1[a,b]$ and $f(a) =0$, I would like to show that
$$\sup_{x\in [a, b]} (f(x)) ^2 \le (b-a) \int_a ^b(f'(x)) ^2 dx$$

My attempt is: using that $f(a) =0$, and the fundamental principle of Calculus, I take
$$f(x) =\int_a^x f'(t) dt$$
so I can express along with Cauchy-Schwartz inequality as follows
$$f^2 (x) =\bigg[\int_a^xf'(t) dt\bigg] ^2\le \int_a^x (f'(t)) ^2dt \int_a^x 1^2dt\le (x-a)\int_a^x (f'(t)) ^2dt. $$

Thus, I finally apply the sup of both side to have

$$\sup_{x\in [a, b]} (f(x)) ^2 \le (b-a) \int_a ^b(f'(x)) ^2 dx. $$

The question I have is that whether what I have done is so far valid or not.

Comment: yes of course, what do you think it could be wrong ?

Comment: @Surb, Thank you. Now I am totally fine with the approach, I just want it be verified.